# Force 'update password' popup using javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, optimization, bootstrap-4, passwords

#### **Problem:**

I am trying to build a webapp with a password change feature that doesn't use a form submit.

The flow is a bit like this:

1. Bootstrap modal popup
2. user enteres text
3. On Modal 'Ok' a fetch is triggered that updates the database.
4. On API confirm **[somehow trigger the 'update your password' dialouge in firefox/chrome/etc.]**

*Due to previous confusion: The 'update your password' dialouge refers to the browser password manager popup that gets
shown when a login form is send.*

[picture of the popup i am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtjEz.png)
(source: https://linuxhint.com/force_firefox_never_save_passwords/)

Tech stack:

In case it is relevant here is my tech-stack:

- Vue.js ( No plugins or modules except VueX )
- Bootstrap (with all the included js)

Code

```html
<h1>Submit form: (Works)</h1>
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<h1>My version (simplified):</h1>
<p>Enter your new password</p>
<input type="text" v-model="password">

<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal">
    <p>Please enter your old password</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="old">
    <button @click="updatePassword">Update</button>
</div>
```

```js
//vue stuff
function updatePassword(){
    // a fetch wrapper
    callAPI( '/api/update_password', { old:this.old, password:this.password } )
}
```

**What i tried:**

I am aware of the fact that i could use a hidden form pointed to a 'dead' endpoint that is submitted by Javascript.

**Why i don't like that solution:**

1. It feels like a hack
2. I don't want to create unecessary requests
3. creating and destroying DOM-Elements for Javascript-only use is not 'the clean way' (as far as i know)
4. This has to be a common thing, am i missing an API?

Thanks in advance!
- Stevetec

Comment: Please take time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask#comment-formatting) on how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: "unecessary requests"?

Comment: What's the `update your password` dialog you're referring to?

Comment: I am refering to the "Firefox has detected a login; do you want me to save it in Firefox Lockwise"? popup that is also used for autocomplete-selection if multiple logins are found. Regarding 'unecessary requests': i thing that fireing a form to an endpoint that does nothing only to get eg. firefox to prompt the previously mentioned popup to be a wasted request)

Comment: @Stevetec the browser does not *want to* allow you to force that. For one, users can disable the feature locally. On top of that, it could allow for some very nasty attacks if the website could force security-related popups.

Comment: @Casey Kuilman Thanks for the info, i did not consider that becuase one would still have to press 'OK' - but i see it now, thanks for answering my question. [please repost your comment as an snswer so i can 'prperly' close this question]

Comment: @Stevetec I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser does not want to allow you to force that. For one, users can disable the feature locally. On top of that, it could allow for some very nasty attacks if the website could force security-related popups.